# Sharing a fan page and counting the numbers of fans linked

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

We would like to count the number of fan generated by one of our fan sharing our facebook fan page, how can we do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, there's no referral tracking for Like buttons like that.
If you were tracking likes of an external URL you could rig something up with referrer URLs and tracking the landing pages, but this won't apply to likes which happen on Facebook itself